# Subclassing Polygon in Shapely

Tags: python, shapely

I'm working with Shapely in Python and trying to subclass the Polygon class. However, I'm encountering an error when trying to add a custom attribute during object creation. Could you please provide guidance on how to subclass the Polygon class in Shapely and add custom attributes without running into this error?

This is what I tried so far:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon


class CustomPolygon(Polygon):

    def __init__(self, shell=None, holes=None, name=None):
        super().__init__(shell, holes)
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value


polygon1 = CustomPolygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)], name="Polygon1")
```

And this is the error I get:

```
polygon1 = CustomPolygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)], name="Polygon1")
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

Comment: You may need to override `__new__` instead of `__init__`; that's typical of immutable Python objects.  Note that you're currently throwing away the value of the `name` parameter, and initializing your added field to None instead.

Comment: even worse, `Polygon` is not the actual class you get when constructing it, it is only a factory, its `__new__` returns other objects that are C extensions ..... afaik you can't add extra properties to extension types unless the extension type allows it (and they don't seem to), you'd have to use a wrapper and use composition instead of inheritance, you could probably have python forward all calls with `__getattr__`.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I also would like to work with MultiPolygon that takes a list of Polygon objects. But that is not possible if I use composition instead of inheritance, right? Is there no other workaround?

Comment: if you are too daring you could modify shapely's types at runtime from C to add to it the support for extra members, but no simple solution comes to mind, this is basically C domain not python.